# How to rename a blazor project

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

So I have a ASP hosted CSB project and the CSB references a blazor lib.

```
   [ASP-host] -> [CSB] -> [My-Blazor-Lib]
```

This works fine.  But if I just rename the server project (e.g. `ASP-host.csproj` to `foopy.csproj`) then it breaks.  While the app starts, I cannot run `My-Blazor-Lib` code because it can't load `_content\My-Blazor-Lib\*.js` files.

Comment: try to delete *.vs*, *bin* and *obj* folders and rebuild

Comment: That worked!  Thanks.